# ADO pipeline variable to use installed nuget version as variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to configure an Azure DevOps pipeline and I have a yaml file with steps that are like this:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Install'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    arguments: install PKGNAME -source PKGSOURCE -outputDirectory F:\CSsyn
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'F:\CSsyn\PKGNAME.16.0.12817.30000\lib\net45\Runner.exe Run --arg1 test1 --arg2 test2
```

It simply installs a nuget package, then runs an executable from that package. The only problem with this is that the command in my `CmdLine` task depends on the specific version of the installed package. Since I'm installing the latest nuget package where the version is changing, I'd like to get it so that the path for the `CmdLine` task is based on a variable for the version of the package that was installed. Something like:

```
script: 'F:\CSsyn\PKGNAME.$(PKGVERSION)\lib\net45\Runner.exe Run --arg1 test1 --arg2 test2
```

I did some digging and saw that [some tasks can reference output variables of other tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) but the [NuGet task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) does not seem to have any output variables (at least from what I can see). Any ideas what I should put in the place of `$(PKGVERSION)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can create a variable from the NuGet task but I have another idea, you can use PowerShell to get the `.exe` file with wildcard and then run it:

```
- powershell: |
   $file = Get-ChildItem "F:\CSsyn\*\lib\net45\Runner.exe"
   & $file Run --arg1 test1 --arg2 test2
```

Comment: Haha - while I was waiting for an answer I came up with a very similar solution (though I am sorting the `Get-ChildItem` results by `LastWriteTime`)